# Exception libraries for C (not C++)

Tags: c, exception, c99, throw, raise

I am rolling my own exception library for C and would like good examples to examine.

So far, I have been looking at David Hanson's:
http://drhanson.net/work/

But I know I've seen other ones available in the past.  Can you send me some additional pointers?

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 3):

[Here is one](http://ldeniau.web.cern.ch/ldeniau/oopc.html#Exception), compatible with C89 and implementing the try/catch/finally schema as can be found in other OO languages.

Answer (score 1):

Symbian implemented exceptions (called 'leaves') in terms of longjmp.  This was C++ code, but translatable to C.  There's a [previous post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819864/what-are-some-good-ways-to-use-longjmp-setjmp-for-c-error-handling/819907#819907).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at XXL: http://www.zork.org/xxl/

I found it quite usable in a previous project.  Hasn't been updated in a while though.

Answer (score 0):

[CException](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cexception/wiki) is simple exception handling in C. It is significantly faster than full-blown C++ exception handling but loses some flexibility. It is portable to any platform supporting setjmp/longjmp.