# Exit Handler in C

Tags: c, exception, error-handling

All,

I want to develop an exit handler in my program.

I'm really new to C; is it all about managing signals in C?

How do I know if my program ended in a good way or not?

If not, how do I get the maximum information when exiting?

Comment: log does much better job.

Comment: @cedrou both of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here you will find all what you want:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/

I added a new link here take a look:

[Exception libraries for C (not C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410329/exception-libraries-for-c-not-c/1632090)

Answer (score 13):

1. C (C89 and C99 standards) provides [`atexit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) to *register function to be called when the program exits*. This has nothing to do with signals. Unlike signal handlers, you can register multiple exit handlers. The exit handlers are called in reverse order of how they were registered with `atexit()`.
2. The convention is that when program exits cleanly it returns exit status `0`. This can be done by `return 0` from `main()` or `exit(0)` from anywhere in your program.
3. In Unix/Linux/POSIX type operating system (not sure of Windows), the parent process get exit status information about the child process using `wait()` system call or its variants.

**Example:** Here is a simple program and its output to demonstrate `atexit()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void exit_handler1(void)
{
    printf("Inside exit_handler1()!n");
}

static void exit_handler2(void)
{
    printf("Inside exit_handler2()!n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    atexit(exit_handler1);
    atexit(exit_handler2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output generated by the program:

```
Inside exit_handler2()!
Inside exit_handler1()!
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not get wrong you ask about giving back results from program when exiting. You should use `exit(x);` function to return value from your program. You can put any integer value as parameter `x`. And dont forget to use `#include <stdlib.h>` in your program start.

Comment: If i have a buffer over flow , i will not be able to get to an exit callback, i want to get safe from any crash.

Comment: @user2122937 - In general there is no way to catch a crash (e.g. writing to an invalid memory address), unless you run your C program under debugger or perhaps use C interpreter.