# Safe usage of `setjmp` and `longjmp`

Tags: c, performance, memory-leaks, setjmp

I know people always say don't use `longjmp`, it's evil, it's dangerous.

But I think it can be useful for exiting deep recursions/nested function calls.

Is a single `longjmp` faster than a lot of repeated checks and returns like `if(returnVal != SUCCESS) return returnVal;`?

As for safety, as long as dynamic memory and other resources are released properly, there shouldn't be a problem, right?

So far it seems using `longjmp` isn't difficult and it even makes my code terser. I'm tempted to use it a lot.

(IMHO in many cases there is no dynamic memory/resources allocated within a deep recursion in the first place. Deep function call seems more common for data parsing/manipulation/validation. Dynamic allocation often happens at a higher level, before invoking the function where `setjmp` appears.)

Comment: It *can* be useful in some cases, as long as you are aware of the possible problems it can cause, and are willing to risk the "spaghetti code" it can produce.

Comment: "*it seems using longjmp isn't difficult and it even makes my code terser*" and more complex, that is more *difficult* to maintain.

Comment: Probably a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/819864/694576

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setjmp` and `longjmp` can be seen as a poor man's [exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) mechanism. BTW, [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) exceptions are as quick as `setjmp` but have a much clearer semantics.

Of course a `longjmp` is much faster than repeatedly returning error codes in intermediate functions, since it pops up a perhaps significant [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) portion.

<sup>(I am implicitly focusing on Linux)</sup>

They are valid and useful as long as no resources are allocated between them, including:

- heap memory (`malloc`)
- `fopen`-ing `FILE*` handles
- opening operating system file descriptors (e.g. for sockets)
- other operating system resources, such as timers or signal handlers
- getting some external resource managed by some server, e.g. X11 windows (hence using any widget toolkit like GTK), or database handle or connection...
- etc...

The main issue is that **that property of not [leaking resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leak) is a global *whole-program* property** (or at least global to all functions possibly called between `setjmp` and `longjmp`), so it prohibits [modular software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) : any other colleague having to improve some code in any function between `setjmp` and `longjmp` has to be aware of that limitation and follow that discipline.

<sup>Hence, if you *use* `setjmp` document that very clearly.</sup>

BTW, if you *only* care about `malloc`, using *systematically* [Boehm's](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) conservative [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) would help a lot; you'll use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` everywhere and you won't care about `free`, and practically that is enough; then you can use `setjmp` without fears (since you could call `GC_malloc` between `setjmp` and `longjmp`).

<sup>(notice that the concepts and the terminology around garbage collector are quite related to exception handling and `setjmp`, but many people don't know them enough. Reading the [Garbage Collection Handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) should be worthwhile)</sup>

Read also about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and learn about [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) exceptions (and their relation to [destructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29)). Learn a bit about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Read [setjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html), [longjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) (and also about `sigsetjmp`, `siglongjmp`, and [setcontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setcontext.3.html)) and be aware that the compiler has to know about `setjmp`

Answer (score 3):

You should note that calling setjmp in some contexts is not guaranteed to be safe (for example, you can't portably store the return value of setjmp).

Also, if you want to access local variables after calling setjmp, in the same function, that could have been changed you should mark that variables as volatile.

Using setjmp and longjmp is also useful because if the recursion causes a Stack Overflow, you can recover with a longjmp from the signal handler (don't forget to set an alternate stack) and return an error instead. If you want to do that you should consider to use sigsetjmp and siglongjmp for preserving signal dispositions.